# My IntelliJ Project Creation isn't providing me with any structure

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In the past 24 hours, I've started having an issue with my IntelliJ not properly structuring projects for me when I create them from a template as a basic java project. I'm not sure why it's doing this, but as you can see in the image, there is absolutely no structure in my project, no src folder or anything. The path is correct on the header bar of the application, but nothing shows in the actual project view.

I thought it might be an issue with the project waiting to load, but I've waited 20+ minutes and nothing seems to change.

Also, if I try to edit the code in the Main class, I get a non-project file protection pop-up, and if I try to run it, I get an Edit Configuration pop-up.

Does anyone know how to fix this and make it work like it should?

[image: Visualisation of the issue]

Comment: What steps did you execute to create this project? What type of project have you chosen in the `New Project` dialog? Which version of IntelliJ IDEA are you running? Which OS are you using?

Comment: I press New Project > Java > Create Project from Template > Give it a name > Finish.

Interestingly enough, the structure is present and everything works fine if I have a project currently open and I use the new function from the navigation bar, but if it's the project selection window when you first open IntelliJ, it doesn't work following the same steps.

My IntellIJ version is 212.4746.92

Comment: The actual version is 2021.2.2 build 212.5284.40 from September 14th. You should try the actual version.